# JavaFX : How to process a webview in a non application thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, performance, javafx, webview

I have a JavaFX application that contains a WebView among other JavaFx views in the same window. The WebView opens a URL to a NodeJs webapp that consumes a lot of CPU resources.

With this resource consumption from the WebView, the other JavaFX views are working slowly.

For our application, we have a very powerful system with 12 virtual threads in the processor.

So, what I need is to deport the WebView processing to another thread so that it won't affect the behavior of the other JavaFX views. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.  JavaFX has a single application thread per JVM process (java invocation) and WebView API calls must be processed on the JavaFX application thread.

Note that internally, the WebView uses WebKit which may have its own threading implementation to support html5 stuff like [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but that is all hidden from you when you are programming WebView at the Java API level.  So that won't make much of a difference unless you explicitly program your JavaScript to make use of it.  I guess if your NodeJS webapp is optimized for other browsers it will probably work fine in WebView, you will just need to benchmark, which I guess you did and found something wanting.  You may want to expend some effort optimizing the NodeJS webapp that you have.

The only way to achieve something similar to what you are requesting in your question is to launch a separate process, i.e., a new JavaFX application in a new JVM process, that contains your WebView instance.